# angular js Reset button not working in IE8

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

```
scope.resetall = function () {
    $scope.website.forEach(function (web) {
        web.CouponID = false;           
    });
};
```

i try to reset radio button using forEach.Its working fine in all browser except IE8.
I am using angular js 1.2.17

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a quick research, I found out that forEach doesn't work well on IE8, try using a good old for loop:

```
for(var i=0; i < $scope.website.length; i++){
    $scope.website[i].CouponID = false;           
}
```